# How to Login only once before each fixture in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I want to run e2e test and for that I want to login only once (before each and every fixture ) in my test framework. I read that I can do it with Role but I do not know how I can deal with all the fixtures across the framework

Moreover, I do login using httpauth, before httpauth I have to enter my email, so is there any way I can handle httpauth via Role or any other way (I want to login only once until all my fixtures gets run)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

At present, to achieve this scenario, for each fixture you need to do the following:

- add the [`fixture.beforeEach`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/beforeeach.html) hook and call [`t.useRole(targetRole)`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/testcontroller/userole.html) in it
- specify authentication information in the [`fixture.httpAuth`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/fixture/httpauth.html) method.

There are two suggestions ([Support `httpAuth` within a Role](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4699) and [Add capability to specify fixture and test hooks on the test run level](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/4323)) in the TestCafe Github repository related to your use case.
Track any of them to be informed of our progress.